# How to get/set correct relative paths in PHP with a lot of directories?

Tags: php, wamp

I have a problem finding the right path for a file. Here is my example. (I run Windows and WAMP)

My main file is placed here:

```
/homedir/subdir2/subdir3/index.php
```

It has to look for the file placed here:

```
/homedir/subdir1/images/slides/image.png
```

My code is:

```
/homedir/subdir2/subdir3/../subdir1/images/slides/image.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go up twice to get to /homedir/

```
../../subdir1/images/slides/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
/homedir/subdir2/subdir3/../../subdir1/images/slides/image.png
```

Note double `../` here.